# zlib 1.2.5 unable to recognize this header

Tags: zlib

I have a source text and its supposedly-zlib deflated embedding (and \ escaping) within another text file. I do not have docs on its encoding other than it uses zlib with nominal escaping for \0, \t, \n, \r, quote, etc.

The unescaped data has:

first four bytes: 1A 9B 02 00
   last four bytes: 76 18 23 82

which inflate complains about having an invalid header.

When I deflate/inflate the matching source text myself using 1.2.5, I get:

first four bytes: 78 9C ED 7D

Can someone suggest what compression is being used given the header bytes? I haven't found any magic numbers or header formula that actually uses those.

EDIT: [Here](http://sdrv.ms/XqObxE) are the relevant files...

- codedreadbase.cohdemo is the source text file with the escaped embedded section following the BASE verb. Escapes are:

  \n = (newline)
  \r = (return)
  \0 = 0 (NULL)
  \t = tab
  \q = "
  \s = '
  \d = $
  \p = %
- codedreadbase.deflated is what I am passing to zlib inflateInit/inflate*/inflateEnd after unescpaing the above within the double quotes.
- codedreadbase.txt is the original text of the embedded section.

Comment: Please supply the full version of the text with the alleged embedded deflate stream.

Comment: Added relevant files to post.

Comment: Stripping 4 front bytes before inflating in case of a prefix didn't help, despite bytes 5-8 looking very close (78 5E ED 7D) to the valid first 4 bytes when I independently deflated the source text myself (78 9C ED 7D).

Answer (score 1):

Your first four bytes, `1A 9B 02 00` are the length of the uncompressed data in little-endian order, 170778 in decimal.  You have indeed found the start of a valid zlib stream with the next four bytes: `78 5E ED 7D`.  You just need to properly extract the binary compressed stream from the escaped format.  I had no problem and decompressed codedreadbase.txt exactly.

You didn't mention one obvious escape, which is the backslash itself.  `\\` should go to `\`.  Maybe that's what you're missing.  This simple un-escaper in C worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\\') {
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == EOF)
                break;
            ch =
                ch == 'n' ? '\n' :
                ch == 'r' ? '\r' :
                ch == '0' ? 0 :
                ch == 't' ? '\t' :
                ch == 'q' ? '"' :
                ch == 's' ? '\'' :
                ch == 'd' ? '$' :
                ch == 'p' ? '%' : ch;
        }
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. But I have 78 5E (not 9C) ED 7D as the stream start after stripping off the little-endian 4 bytes (which is the first 5 bytes after unescaping the '\\' '0'). I only get the correct 78 9C ED 7D sequence when I perform the deflate and inflate on the original source text file without messing with the already-embedded version. So zlib still doesn't like the 78 5E ... as a header for me. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Why do you say "zlib still doesn't like the 78 5E"?  Did you actually try?  It works fine, as I said: "I had no problem and decompressed codedreadbase.txt exactly."

Comment: Yes, I am using inflateInit2 with windowBits = 16+MAX_WBITS (bad header) and also tried with windowBits = -MAX_WBITS (gets states HEAD, TYPEDO, STORED and fails there with invalid stored block lengths). I am pursuing the -MAX_WBITS choice since it at least gets past the header, and rechecking my unescaping and such.

Comment: Nevermind, I either needed to use just inflateInit, or pass MAX_WBITS to inflateInit2 and it worked like a charm. Thank you sir.